# Altera posição de um ponto no Google maps

Tags: google-maps

Bom preciso alterar a posição de um maps sem criar um novo ponto. Preciso de apenas atualizar o ponto.

Código produzido:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //variaveis globais.
        var map;
        var marker;

        // Resultado para quando conseguir capturar a posição GPS...
    var fnCapturar = function(position){

        // Gravar dados da posição capturada em uma variável...
        var coords = position.coords;

        // Exibir dados das coordenadas capturadas...
       // navigator.notification.alert(JSON.stringify(coords),"COORDENADAS");

         // GOOGLE MAPS: Mostrar marcador no mapa...
        if(!map){    
            map = new google.maps.Map(
                            document.getElementById("map"), 
                            { 
                              center : new google.maps.LatLng( coords.latitude, coords.longitude ), 
                              zoom : 15, 
                              mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
                            }
                    );
        }
        if(!marker){
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                title : "VOCÊ ESTÁ AQUI: "+coords.latitude+", "+coords.longitude,
                position : new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude),
             });
            marker.setMap(map);
        }else{
            marker = '0';
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                title : "VOCÊ ESTÁ AQUI: "+coords.latitude+", "+coords.longitude,
                position : new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude),
             });
            marker.setMap(map);
        }
    }

    // Caso falhe na captura, faça isso...
    var fnFalhar = function(error){

        navigator.notification.alert("É necessario a conectividade com a internet !", "INFORMAÇÃO");

    }          

    // Opções para acessar o GPS...
    var opcoes = { maximumAge: 1000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true }; 

    // CAPTURAR POSIÇÃO: Chamada a API de Geolocalização (GPS) via Apache Cordova
    var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(fnCapturar, fnFalhar, opcoes);       
    </script>
```

Comment: Alterando as variáveis coords.latitude e coords.longitude

Comment: Isso eu sei ue kkkk, mais ja conseguir uma solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //variaveis globais.
        var map;
        var marker;

        // Resultado para quando conseguir capturar a posição GPS...
    var fnCapturar = function(position){

        // Gravar dados da posição capturada em uma variável...
        var coords = position.coords;

        // Exibir dados das coordenadas capturadas...
       // navigator.notification.alert(JSON.stringify(coords),"COORDENADAS");

         // GOOGLE MAPS: Mostrar marcador no mapa...
        if(!map){    
            map = new google.maps.Map(
                            document.getElementById("map"), 
                            { 
                              center : new google.maps.LatLng( coords.latitude, coords.longitude ), 
                              zoom : 15, 
                              mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
                            }
                    );
        }
        if(!marker){
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                title : "VOCÊ ESTÁ AQUI: "+coords.latitude+", "+coords.longitude,
                position : new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude),
             });
            marker.setMap(map);
        }else{
            marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude) );   
        }
    }

    // Caso falhe na captura, faça isso...
    var fnFalhar = function(error){

        navigator.notification.alert("É necessario a conectividade com a internet !", "INFORMAÇÃO");

    }          

    // Opções para acessar o GPS...
    var opcoes = { maximumAge: 1000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true }; 

    // CAPTURAR POSIÇÃO: Chamada a API de Geolocalização (GPS) via Apache Cordova
    var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(fnCapturar, fnFalhar, opcoes);       
    </script>
```

Bastava adicionar:

> }else{
>                   marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude) );
>               }